# Test that a method was called on a variable inside a method that returns Void

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Assuming I have a method, such as this:

```
Object myRandomObject;

...

void foo(boolean input) {
    if(input) {
        myRandomObject.toString(); 
    }
}
```

How can I write a `jUnit` test to just test that `toString()` method was actually called on `myRandomObject`?

Comment: Can you pass your own `myRandomObject` from test?

Comment: is this `myRandomObject` mocked object?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it doesn't matter, it's representative code, that narrows down all the unnecessary details. I need just a way to test whether the method was called on an object, regardless of its nature.

Comment: @Deadpool it could be, I just need a guide on how to test method being called on a variable.

Comment: @SerjArdovic, it matters quite a lot whether your test owns the object in question. Otherwise, what are you going to test? That method called on any instance of said class? But that's useless, because you can't know what exact object it was called on. How do you know your unit uses its parameters, and doesn't just create new objects to call a method on them once and then discard?

Answer (score 2):

If your `myRandomObject` simply mock itself with some test class definition with overriden `toString` implementation, setting up some flag then assert on this flag

```
private class TestRandomObject {
    private boolean toStringCalled;

    @Override
    public String toString {
        this.toStringCalled = true;
        return "test";
    }
}
```

<s>Or even you can use Mockito `verify` method like</s>

```
Object randomObjectMock = mock(Object.class); 
// ...
verify(randomObjectMock , times(1)).toString();
```

**EDIT** no you cannot :) It will give you an expception like with quite funny message

> Mockito cannot verify toString()
>
> toString() is too often used behind of scenes  (i.e. during String concatenation, in IDE debugging views)

They say that you can `stub` this method, but even stubbing this will not allow you to `verify` later. Therefore seems that my first suggestion is the working one

Comment: I see, it's a way to go, thought of it too. However, I wonder if there is any shorter way, maybe a function that checks whether the method was called on a variable? Thank you anyways!

Comment: yes you can use `verify` Mockito method - I've updated my answer

Comment: Oh, thank you, that seems to be what I was looking for, let me check it and return back to approve if that solves my problem..

Comment: I've checked meanwhile and it seems that Mockito has some funny `toString` "issue" I was not aware of. Updated my answer and sorry for misleading